# How to shift values from one div panel to other in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a Form, there are multiple div Panels

```
<form>
<div class="panel1">
  <input type="text" value="" name="bank0" id="bank0">
  <input type="text" value="" name="shank0" id="shank0">
  <input type="text" value="" name="dhank0" id="dhank0">
  <input type="text" value="" name="raank0" id="raank0">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="panel2">
  <input type="text" value="" name="bank1" id="bank1">
  <input type="text" value="" name="shank1" id="shank1">
  <input type="text" value="" name="dhank1" id="dhank1">
  <input type="text" value="" name="raank1" id="raank1">
</div>
</form>
```

**Requirement**: 
If user left panel1 blank and entered text to panel 2; 
then we want to shift all values from panel 2 to panel 1; during final submission of form.

In real use case we have 10 such panels.
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rop5f0d6/

Comment: Is that answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```js
var inputsValue = [];
$("button").click(function () {
    $(".panel2 input").each(function () {
        inputsValue.push(this.value);
    });
    $(".panel1 input").each(function (i, value) {
        $(this).val(inputsValue[i]);
    });
    inputsValue = [];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel1">
    <input type="text" value="" name="bank0" id="bank0">
    <input type="text" value="" name="shank0" id="shank0">
    <input type="text" value="" name="dhank0" id="dhank0">
    <input type="text" value="" name="raank0" id="raank0">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="panel2">
    <input type="text" value="" name="bank1" id="bank1">
    <input type="text" value="" name="shank1" id="shank1">
    <input type="text" value="" name="dhank1" id="dhank1">
    <input type="text" value="" name="raank1" id="raank1">
</div>
<hr>
<button>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will only move the data from panel 2 to panel 1 if the first panel is left blank (what I read from the requirements).

Also it wipes panel 2 data to prevent duplicate form data being posted. From your question I think this is what you are aiming for?

Here is how you can implement this functionality in jQuery:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  var moveData = true, formvalues = [];

  $(".panel1 input").each(function(e, field){
    if( field.value != '' ){
      moveData = false;
      return false;
    }
  });

  // only move data if first panel is blank
  if( moveData ){
    $(".panel2 input").each(function(){
      formvalues.push( this.value );
      this.value = '';
    });
    
    $(".panel1 input").each(function (i) {
      this.value = formvalues[i];
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel1">
  <input type="text" value="" name="bank0" id="bank0">
  <input type="text" value="" name="shank0" id="shank0">
  <input type="text" value="" name="dhank0" id="dhank0">
  <input type="text" value="" name="raank0" id="raank0">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="panel2">
  <input type="text" value="" name="bank1" id="bank1">
  <input type="text" value="" name="shank1" id="shank1">
  <input type="text" value="" name="dhank1" id="dhank1">
  <input type="text" value="" name="raank1" id="raank1">
</div>
<hr>
<button>Submit</button>
```

I've also written the solution in vanilla JS for your reference (possibly useful) as plain JS is more efficient in performance.

```js
var submitBtn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var moveData = true,
      formvalues = [],
      panel1 = document.getElementsByClassName("panel1"),
      panel1Fields = panel1[0].getElementsByTagName("input"),
      panel2 = document.getElementsByClassName("panel2"),
      panel2Fields = panel2[0].getElementsByTagName("input");

  for(var i=0; i < panel1Fields.length; i++){
    if( panel1Fields[i].value != '' ){
      moveData = false;
      return false;
    }
  }

  // only move data if first panel is blank
  if( moveData ){
    for(var i=0; i < panel2Fields.length; i++){
      formvalues.push( panel2Fields[i].value );
      panel2Fields[i].value = '';
    }

    for(var i=0; i < panel1Fields.length; i++){
      panel1Fields[i].value = formvalues[i];
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="panel1">
  <input type="text" value="" name="bank0" id="bank0">
  <input type="text" value="" name="shank0" id="shank0">
  <input type="text" value="" name="dhank0" id="dhank0">
  <input type="text" value="" name="raank0" id="raank0">
</div>
<div class="panel2">
  <input type="text" value="" name="bank1" id="bank1">
  <input type="text" value="" name="shank1" id="shank1">
  <input type="text" value="" name="dhank1" id="dhank1">
  <input type="text" value="" name="raank1" id="raank1">
</div>
<button>Send</button>
```